# Check for new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an interesting dilema. I have an application that when a new record, in this case a user, is created it is published to another application (specific information is).

Now I could use `User.last` and get the latest and greatest. Publishing happens as soon as the record is saved and it only takes a second. So assume I have 500 users signing up at once.

Thats 500 new records published to the second app, For each of those I need to say:

**If this user is new, do x with it, else ignore it.**

I am using the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to create a cron job on the second app that watches every 5 seconds for new records. in that time 5 new recods could come through so I need to update the above statement to say:

**If the record is 5 seconds or younger do x with it, else ignore it.**

Can I do the following:

```
Users.all.each do |u|
  *if u is 5 seconds or less old*
    do something here
  end
end
```

I am not sure what the if statement would be, would it be `u.created_at <= 5.seconds` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.where('created_at >= ?', 5.seconds.ago)` will find records that are no more than five seconds old.  But it sounds like you might be better off with an API that would push create events to your second app.

Comment: I am using pub sub and rabbit mq. I have a gem that handles all this for me. I am slowly moving to an API.

Answer (score 1):

You *could*. It would look like this:

```
gauge = Time.now - 5
Users.all.each do |u|
  u.created_at >= gauge
    # do something here
  end
end
```

The issue is that it takes time to run the loop. Even if you ran a more efficient query, you're still relying on timestamps for a high level of precision.

```
User.where('created_at >= ?', Time.now - 5)
```

If there's a delay in the system, say the computer takes .5 seconds to get to your query, you'll miss any users created in the .5 second gap. Better to add a `published` column to Users, mark the record as published, and then check for unpublished records.

```
users = User.where(published: nil)
users.each { |u| u.publish }
```

Or, as another post mentioned, look for an API that will push create events.

Comment: as already stated in anther comment I have a pub sub system in place that uses rabbit mq to publish, essentially, models and attributes from one app to another that is subscribing. But eventually ill be moving towards an API.

Comment: This is a very good point.  If the cron is delayed for even a second for any reason (high system load or whatever) then any users created in that second will be lost to the second app.

Comment: so in the mean time should I add a larger time gap? Until I can move to an API based system?

Comment: No. A larger gap will mean you're processing in duplicate. Mark your records as processed and then query for unprocessed records, rather than relying on time differences.